# HTML Layout positioning & Image borders

Tags: html, css

This is what I need to build [Mockup](http://dh-creative-webdesign.de/mockup.html)

Now I have this [Site](http://dh-creative-webdesign.de/rw-fliesen.html)

As you can see first the two images on the top of content have only half borders.

Then the text sections with the beside image is not on the right place. And the top border of the image should be in one line with the beside text.
I've tried some adjustments, but nothing helped.

What can be done to fix both issues?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>RW-Fliesen</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />



</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">



            <div id="header">

                    <a href="index.html" class="logo"     title="Logo"></a>

                    <div class="contact-info" title="contact-    info"></div>

                    <ul class="mn">
                    <li><a href=" " title="" class="mn1 "></a>    </li>
                    <li><a href=" " title="" class="mn2 "></a></li>
                    <li><a href=" " title="" class="mn3 "></a></li>
                    <li><a href=" " title="" class="mn4 "></a></li>
                    <li><a href=" " title="" class="mn5 "></a></li>
                    <li><a href=" " title="" class="mn6 "></a></li>
                    </ul>

            </div>


            <div id="content">

                <div id="top">  
                        <div class="foto1" title="Fliesen">     <img src="foto1.png" alt="Fliesen1"/> </div>    
                        <div class="foto2" title="Fliesen"> <img src="foto2.png" alt="Fliesen2"/> </div>        
                </div>



                <div id="leftcolumn">       


                        <div class="text" title="text">

                        <p> RW-Fliesen <br />
                            Ludwig-Thoma-Str. 36 <br />
                            82008 Unterhaching </p>


                                <div class="text2"     title="text">
                                <p> Telefon: <br />
                                    Fax: <br />
                                    Mobil: <br     />
                                    Email: <br />
                                </p>
                                </div>

                                <div class="text3" title="text">
                                <p> 089 - 358 557     88 <br />
                                    089 - 358 557 89 <br />
                                    0179 - 673 77 41 <br />
                                    info@rw-    fliesen.com <br />
                                </p>    
                                </div>

                        <div class="text4" title="text">


                        <p> Betriebsnummer: 7084943 <br />    <span class="text-blue"> Eingetragen in die Handwerksrolle bei <br /> der Handwerkskammer     für München <br /> und Oberbayern. </span>   </p>



                        </div>




                        </div>




                        <div class="face" title="face">
                        <iframe id="f580fdad4"     name="f83387924" scrolling="no" style="border: none; overflow: hidden; height: 684px; width: 262px;" class="fb_ltr" src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?api_key=&amp;locale=de_DE&amp;sdk=joey&amp;channel=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D18%23cb%3Dfe1e61258%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.rw-fliesen.com%252Ff21318bbdc%26domain%3Dwww.rw-fliesen.com%26relation%3Dparent.parent&amp;height=290&amp;header=true&amp;show_faces=true&amp;stream=false&amp;width=262&amp;href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FRW-Fliesen%2F115860578491339&amp;colorscheme=light"></iframe>
                        </div>



                </div>



                <div id="rightcolumn">


                        <div class="text5" title="text">

                        <p> Wir sind Ihr fachlich     kompetenter Fliesenleger- und Innenausbaubetrieb in Unterhaching.  </p><br />

                        <p> Als Fachbetrieb mit langjähriger Erfahrung in Fliesenverlegung und Innenausbau bieten wir Ihnen hohe handwerkliche Qualität, wertvolle Materialien sowie faire Preise. </p><br />

                        <p> Unsere Leistungen: </p>
                        <ul>
                        <li> Beratung & Verlegung von     Fliesen, Platten, Naturstein und Mosaik vom Fachmann﻿ </li>
                        <li> Individuelle und exclusive Bad- und Wohnraumgestaltung </li>
                        <li> Vermittlung von Handwerksmeisterbetrieben ( Installlateur, Elektriker, Maurer, Maler, Schreiner, Bodenleger) </li>
                        <li> Trockenbau </li>
                        <li> Estrichverlegung </li>
                        <li> Innenausbau </li>
                        <li> Reparaturarbeiten </li>
                        <li> Entrümpelung </li>
                        <li> Zusammenstellen eines Teams zur Kompletten Renovierung & Bauaufsicht </li>
                        </ul>
                        </div>

                        <img src="img1.png" alt="img"     class="img1" />
                        <p> Sie möchten Renovieren, Ihre Wohnräume neu und exclusiv gestalten?

                            Ob groß, oder klein spielt hier keine Rolle, selbst aus einem 5m² Bad kann man einen echten "Eyecatcher" machen!

                            Gerne erstellen wir Ihnen ein individuelles Angebot zu Ihrem Bauvorhaben, beraten Sie zu verschiedenen Möglichkeiten der Durchführung und Gestaltung, sowie neuen Produkten und Materialien in der Baubranche.﻿
                            Erfahren Sie mehr über unser Leistungsspektrum auf den folgenden Seiten. </p>

                </div>



                <div id="footer">



                </div>



            </div>



</div>



</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body { background: #1c1b17 url(bg.jpg) repeat-x; margin: 0; padding: 0; height: auto;     font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px;}

ul, p { color: #373b3f; line-height: 18px; font-size: 13px; font-weight: 600; }
h3 { color: #003d7a; font-size: 10px; font-weight: 600; margin-top: 0px; padding: 0px;     }    
h4 { color: #2f303f; font-size: 13px; font-weight: 600; margin-top: 20px; padding: 0px; }       

.text-blue {     color: #003d7a; line-height: 16px; padding: 0; font-size: 10px;     font-weight: 600; }
.img1 { float: left; margin: 0 20px 10px 0; padding: 0; border: #FFF 3px solid; }   


#wrapper { width: 1000px; height: 800px; margin: 0 auto; }
#header { height: 400px; width: 1000px; display: block; position: relative; }
#header .logo { position: absolute; width: 374px; height: 221px; display: block; float:     left; cursor: pointer; background: url(logo.png) 0 0 no-repeat transparent; top: 55px;     left: 10px; }
#header .contact-info { position: absolute; width: 293px; height: 133px; display:     block; float: left; cursor: pointer; background: url(contact-info.png) 0 0 no-repeat     transparent; top: 100px; left: 700px; }

ul.mn { position: absolute; float: left; top: 316px; width: 978px; margin: 0; padding:     0; list-style-type: none; }
ul.mn li { float: left; }
ul.mn li a { display: block; float: left; height: 73px; }
ul.mn li a.mn1 { width: 104px; background-image: url('mn1.png'); background-position: 0     0; }
ul.mn li a.mn2 { width: 212px; background-image: url('mn2.png'); }
ul.mn li a.mn3 { width: 142px; background-image: url('mn3.png'); }
ul.mn li a.mn4 { width: 128px; background-image: url('mn4.png'); }
ul.mn li a.mn5 { width: 117px; background-image: url('mn5.png'); }
ul.mn li a.mn6 { width: 147px; background-image: url('mn6.png'); }
ul.mn li a.active, ul.mn li a:hover { background-position: 0 73px; }

#content { height: 1000px; width: 1000px; display: block; position: relative; }

#top { height: 300px; width: 1000px; display: block; position: relative; margin-bottom:     100px; }
#top .foto1 { width: 452px; height: 139px; float: left; margin-top: 30px; border: 3px solid #FFF; }
#top .foto2 { width: 253px; height: 138px; float: left; margin-top: 30px; margin-left:     100px; border:#FFF 3px solid; }

#leftcolumn { height: 800px; width: 300px; display: block; position: relative; float: left; }
#leftcolumn .text { height: 10px; width: 300px; display: block; position: relative;     margin-bottom: 0px; }
#leftcolumn .text2 { height: 10px; width: 50px; display: inline-block; position:     relative; }
#leftcolumn .text3 { height: 10px; width: 200px; display: inline-block; position: relative;  padding-left: 30px; }
#leftcolumn .text4 { height: 10px; width: 300px; display: inline-block; position: relative; margin-top: 80px; }
#leftcolumn .face { height: 100px; width: 300px; display: block; position: relative; margin-top: 290px; }

#rightcolumn { height: 800px; width: 700px; display: inline-block; position: absolute;     margin-left: 310px; margin-top: 0px; float: right; }
#rightcolumn  .text5 { height: 300px; width: 700px; display: inline-block; position: relative; }

#footer
```

Answer (score 0):

Your .foto1 and .foto2 classes are forcing the size of the DIV that wraps the img. Just take the height style off of foto1 & foto2.

Besides the aforementioned... try using the FireBug plug-in for FireFox or Google Chrome's web developer tools to diagnose the problems. I'd systematically try turning off CSS styles until you get the results you are looking for.

For the DIV around the two images try tweaking the margin-bottom and padding-bottom styles.

Hope that helps you. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you @viscro. I tried it, but it gave me this output http://dh-creative-webdesign.de/rw-fliesen2.html

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted? It looks like the white borders now entirely wrap the two images. :)

Comment: yes, but on the bottom on the images remains a space and the rest content is not at the right position like I described in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<div>` tags surrounding the images and then apply the styles of the divs to the images themselves. Leave out the width and height and you will have everything working how you want. Here is a sample of code to give you the idea, eventually remember to try and move as much styling out into a `<style>` tag or a css file.

```
<div id="top">
    <img src="foto1.png" alt="Fliesen1" style="float: left; margin-top: 30px; border: 3px solid #FFF;"/>
    <img src="foto2.png" alt="Fliesen2" style="float: left; margin-top: 30px; border: 3px solid #FFF; margin-left: 100px;" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. It gives me that output http://dh-creative-webdesign.de/rw-fliesen.html. I am confused now how all elements are relating to each other. Can you help me out?

Comment: This isn't really supposed to be a tutorial. Join a local school for web development or search for some HTML/CSS tutorials online. Is your question answered satisfactorily?

Answer (score 0):

I believe answer to the second part of your question can be accomplished by changing the position of the ending tag for the text 5 div and inserting line breaks 
 where desired.  I believe the text 5 div section should read as follows:

```
<div class="text5" title="text">

                        <p> Wir sind Ihr fachlich     kompetenter Fliesenleger- und Innenausbaubetrieb in Unterhaching.  </p><br />

                        <p> Als Fachbetrieb mit langjähriger Erfahrung in Fliesenverlegung und Innenausbau bieten wir Ihnen hohe handwerkliche Qualität, wertvolle Materialien sowie faire Preise. </p><br />

                        <p> Unsere Leistungen: </p>
                        <ul>
                            <li> Beratung & Verlegung von     Fliesen, Platten, Naturstein und Mosaik vom Fachmann﻿ </li>
                            <li> Individuelle und exclusive Bad- und Wohnraumgestaltung </li>
                            <li> Vermittlung von Handwerksmeisterbetrieben ( Installlateur, Elektriker, Maurer, Maler, Schreiner, Bodenleger) </li>
                            <li> Trockenbau </li>
                            <li> Estrichverlegung </li>
                            <li> Innenausbau </li>
                            <li> Reparaturarbeiten </li>
                            <li> Entrümpelung </li>
                            <li> Zusammenstellen eines Teams zur Kompletten Renovierung & Bauaufsicht </li>
                        </ul>
                   <!-- </div> this is where you inserted your ending tag in the HTML code you provided-->

                    <img src="img1.png" alt="img"     class="img1" />
                    <p> Sie möchten Renovieren, Ihre Wohnräume neu und exclusiv gestalten?<br/><br/>

                        Ob groß, oder klein spielt hier keine Rolle, selbst aus einem 5m² Bad kann man einen echten "Eyecatcher" machen!<br/><br/><br/>

                        Gerne erstellen wir Ihnen ein individuelles Angebot zu Ihrem Bauvorhaben, beraten Sie zu verschiedenen Möglichkeiten der Durchführung und Gestaltung, sowie neuen Produkten und Materialien in der Baubranche.﻿
                        Erfahren Sie mehr über unser Leistungsspektrum auf den folgenden Seiten. </p>
                     </div> <!-- This is where I believe you should end text 5 div -->
```